# Convert prolog application to a JVM based language?

Tags: java, clojure, jvm, prolog

I have a legacy ISO prolog application of medium size that I would like to move to a JVM based language. The application is a command line tool that parses text files, does some evaluation/transformations and then export a text based file.

My team develops mainly in Java so we have a lot of existing java competence and reusable components. Prolog competence is however very low.

I don't expect there to be a tool that takes prolog source code and transform it to some other language. But I'm trying to understand what would be the easiest solution. Starting from scratch in Java or using a more functional language like Clojure?

Comment: Are you sure you need functional programming? What does the app really do? There are many java libraries for text transformation and evaluation - jakarta, velocity, ...

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj And why that is a problem? Clojure is a JVM language and can use any existing JVM library.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj And by they way, there is not library called 'Jakarta'. Jakarta was an umbrella for many Java projects.

Comment: I don't say it's a problem. I only wonder if it's necessary. Anything can be done in pure java and it depends on the specific task if it's better to learn new programming paradigm or do it with the technologies the team has already experience with. And you're right about jakarta of course, I should have said apache commons.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj Actually functional programming languages excels for tasks such the OP has. Because FP is vital when it comes to data transformation and data flow.

Comment: Is there really no Prolog implementation on the JVM? Not even a library?

Comment: What about this? http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj, regarding Gnu Prolog for Java. Yes, I found that as well. But it does not seem actively used and maintained in the community.

Comment: Those who put the question on hold have way, way more reputation than I do, but I wonder whether this question should be allowed despite being borderline.  The question is vague, and the answers may be all over the place, but OP has a very practical question, and needs some guidance in order to get to a more concrete question or questions.  (Or maybe the question should be moved to Programmers.SE.)

Comment: @Mars - It is not borderline at all.  There are clearly many possible approaches to this, and it is clearly a matter of opinion which would be the easiest approach >>for his team<<.  The fact that the OP needs help does not make this a suitable question. What he really needs is a Prolog expert (i.e. a consultant) to sit with him and his team to work out a solution.

Answer (score 5):

> But I'm trying to understand what would be the easiest solution.

Some implementations of Prolog run on the JVM platform.  Wikipedia lists 5 of them here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Prolog_implementations.  So maybe the easiest solution is train someone in your team in Prolog, and just port the application to a JVM Prolog implementation.  (Which might be a simple thing ...)

Someone on your team is likely to need Prolog skills anyway to successfully translate Prolog to some other language.

---

However, I recognize that there could be other reasons to translate; e.g. if the existing Prolog code needs a major overhaul anyway.

Answer (score 2):

That is mainly depending on your team's skill. You mentioned that your team has a pretty good Java skills; why not starting with that?

If they don't know LISP, they will spent a lot of time learning it from the scratch. Learning LISP is quite an investment but it is definitely pays in the end.

Although Clojure is going to help you a lot in your case (because of data flow and data transformation), I would say that Java is a better bet since your team is competent with it.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using Clojure together with [core.logic](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic) ([tutorial](https://github.com/swannodette/logic-tutorial)) which is a [miniKanren](http://minikanren.org/) implementation. You would need some logic/functional programming skills but you could stay on the JVM.

Comment: +1 for core.logic - it's a finely crafted and very efficient tool that I've used successfully to solve a few logic programming problems.

Answer (score -2):

Prolog is so different from java and other Object Oriented Language. I studied this language to see an other way of programming.
But I dont think there is a magic solution to convert prolog app to a java app. The logic is not the same and no other language is like Prolog. I think you will have to analyse what your prolog app does exactly and go from scractch with a new java app.